# One mysql database or schema per client

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have given a requirement to provide one db per client, After going through most of the links I was able to make some progress.
This is how I have implemented, Depending on the URL entered we are getting the company or client information and based on that we are fetching the data source information for that particular client from tomcat's context.xml file

For company1 and

```
<Resource name="company2db"  auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" password="orion123" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/company1db" username="root"/>
```

for company2,I am dynamically setting the data source using the following code

```
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("company1db");
        System.out.println("connection name "+ds.getConnection().toString());
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from user");
        while (rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "  " + rs.getString(2) + "  " + rs.getString(3));
        conn.close();
```

Do I have to do the repeat the same steps for every service call or is there a way to set this once during login and use the same data source until the user logs out or until the session expires.. In our current scenario we are interacting with the database using EntityManager

Comment: Is this a web application or a desktop application? How many users (= how many open connections) would you expect? In general, to improve scalability, you should not keep resources open for too long, but opening and closing connections frequently also can degrade system performance. You could use connection pooling.

Comment: @MoritzPetersen It is a web application and there might be many users